# Deployment: Best Practices (and real practices)

Tags: deployment

One thing that I've learnt in my short dev career is that there are best practices (like TDD) and then there are actual practices that occur under pressure, or through budgetary/time constraints.

I'm working in a small PHP dev team on a project using Zend framework. The project has the potential to demand a lot of scalability, and so we are trying to establish a good development environment to promote ease of development long term. Architectural patterns/practices aside, I'm looking at trying to automate deployment, checking code quality through svn hooks, possibly even setting up a CI environment.

So I'm interested in hearing people's experience of deployment practices. I've checked other examples as they pertain to other languages - but I'm ideally looking to hear from people who have worked in a PHP/Zend environment

To make the question less vague:
What are people's experiences of using deployment systems like phpUnderControl and rSync?

Comment: rsync is great for ensuring that files in a given folder on computer A are identical to files in another given folder on computer B.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are setting up the development processes for a team, you need to make the official way to do it so easy that no one would even conceive of doing it any other way.

When the pressure is on, automated builds that run the unit tests, create the release disks, set up the QA environments just make life easier for everyone, and make it that much harder for a bug to slip through, and for bugs to appear late in the product development.

Comment: I agree, and looking back at my answer, I didn't even mention a separate build server.

Answer (score 7):

Basically it needs to be easy (if everything is acceptable) to deploy.  This usually means, that after a checkin the system rebuilds automatically.  If ok, the user can at a single click cause the test server to update to the new version.

You should be able to roll-back as easy.

The easier to use you can keep it, the happier people will be.

If at all possible set up a CI.  <strike>Hudson</strike> Jenkins is nice, but there are plenty others.  You WILL appreciate it quickly.